# Django - how add User specific Items?

Tags: python, django

Good day Stackoverflow,
a user should be able to add multiple titles instead of always overwriting the one added title.

\\ views.py

```
def edit_profile(request):

    try:
        profile = request.user.userprofile
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/test')
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

        return render(request, 'forms.html', {'form': form, 'profile': profile})
```

\\models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

\\forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('title',)
```

Then the user has a form on the website where he can add the specific title.

Until now, however, every time the user fills out the title form, the value in the database is overwritten.
As it should be:
When a new title is added in the form, it should simply be added to it.

At the end I should have the possibility, with a Foor loop in the HTML template, to display all the added titles of the respective user.

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: For your User model, are you using a `OneToManyField` or a `OneToOneField` to store `userprofile`?

Comment: UserProfile has `OneToOneField`, it's redundant to have same backwards.

Comment: @dbo123 I don't know, I just used the basic user model

Comment: @NixonSparrow what changes are needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new model and assign new with the ForeignKey field.

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join([title for title in self.titles.all()])


class UserTitle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='titles')
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.userprofile = request.user.userprofile
            form.save()
            return redirect('/test')
    ...
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from your_app.models import UserProfile

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'user', '__str__']

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'your_app',
    ...
```

In template, to make for loop just use:

```
{% for title in user.userprofile.titles.all %}
    {{ title }}
{% endfor %}
```

or if you need only User titles in single string:

```
{{ user.userprofile }}
```

Comment: But how does the views.py look like?

Comment: Sorry, I will add it in a second :)

Comment: Does not work yet, the "User:" in the User Titles in Admin Dashboard is empty

Comment: Edited just now, if that don't help, I'll be here in few hours to help more :)

Comment: Thank you very much but this brings more errors than before. "User:" in admin dashboard is empty, I can't access the site anymore "The view usertest.views.edit_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." and so on

Comment: I have added some more hints. The HttpResonse didn't give you anything because every view has to render something. I didn't give you all code but solution to issue you brought. You will not see anything in User admin, only in UserProfile. It is because you are using User model directly from Django, it means you will not change that model. But you can freely change UserProfile.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a relational database, this functionality isn't *really* supported for a single field. Though, if you really wanted to, you could use a JSON field to make this work.

However, it is probably a better idea to use a separate table for titles.

To do this, you need to create a new `Title` object like:
`class Title(models.Model):`

Then, create a many-to-one relationship using `ForeignKey`:

```
class Title(models.Model): 
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The on_delete method is required. This particular one will delete all Titles associated with a UserProfile if a UserProfile is deleted.

Now, if you want to associate a title object with a UserProfile, you would do it like this:

```
profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)
title = Title.objects.create(text='My Very First Title', user_profile=profile)
```

For more info on many-to-one relationships in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/